# Copulas and relationships between stock returns

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have little knowledge about copulas and I dont know what should I do with data of stocks returns if I want to determine the relationship between returns. 
I know there are such copulas:

lowerBound(X, Y) = max(X + Y - 1, 0)

productCopula(X, Y) = X * Y

upperBound(X, Y) = min(X, Y)

How can I determine the relationship between returns using this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is your copula independed?